# Extracting particular word from existing Sentence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following string
[image]

My idea is to extract particular word and update the same in different column. For e.g

[image]

I could not get an idea how to extract the same

Comment: simple approach would be splitting text using regex. Can you provide more data ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
my_string ="TT Load:Route1 TT Load for 30 out of 80 from Route 2"
description=my_string.split(":")[0]
route_start = my_string.find('Route')
route_end= my_string.find('Route')+6
route= my_string[route_start : route_end]
TTLoad = my_string[route_end:].split('TT Load')
res = [int(i) for i in TTLoad[1].split() if i.isdigit()]
TTLoad_value= res[0]
Out_Of = my_string[route_end:].split('out of')
res = [int(i) for i in Out_Of[1].split() if i.isdigit()]
Out_Of_value= res[0]
required_dict={ "GivenDescription":my_string,
            "Description":description,
             "Route": route,
             "TTLoad" :TTLoad_value,
             "Out of" : Out_Of_value}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(required_dict,orient='index').T
```

Comment: Let me know if this works out for you @ Stunner Dew